# xskak package: castling for Fischerandomchess /Chess960

Tags: xskak

In xskak castling is "hard-wired": kings are expected on e1/e8, rooks on a1h1/a8h8. In Chess960 (shuffle the pieces on 1./8. rank in a certain way) the destination squares of castling are the very same as in "normal chess" ("normal chess" is a spcific Chess960 position..), but the starting squares differ: wKings's square is anywhre between b1 and g1, while the Rooks are positioned one left of the King (for 0-0-0) and one right of the King (for 0-0) 
How cand "Move-from" and "Move" be generalized in xskak for Chess960? Move-to can keep unchanged, and this general approach will just work fine with "normal chess".

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded a test version to https://github.com/u-fischer/xskak/tree/chess960. To use it get the `xskak.dtx` and the `xskak.ins`, put them in some folder and then run `pdflatex xskak.ins` to unpack `xskak.sty`. ^

With this version you can setup the king/rook position for chess960 and castle. It is isn't very much tested. If you see get a problem, add an issue at the github site.

```
  \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage{xskak} %development version 1.6!!
   \setchessboard{smallboard,showmover=false}

   \begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    % set start position of rook for xskak:

    \renewcommand\xskak@king@pos{c}
    \renewcommand\xskak@rookshort@pos{d}
    \renewcommand\xskak@rooklong@pos{b}

    % set start position of rook for skak:
    \def\CastleRookFromFile#1{#1{b}{d}}
    \newchessgame[setpieces={Kc1,Rd1,kc8,rd8}]
    \chessboard
    \mainline{1. O-O O-O}
    \chessboard

     \xskakset{moveid=1w}\xskakget{movefrom}--\xskakget{moveto}, \xskakset{moveid=1b}\xskakget{movefrom}--\xskakget{moveto}

    \newchessgame[setpieces={Kc1,Rb1,kc8,rb8}]
    \chessboard
    \mainline{1. O-O-O O-O-O}
    \chessboard

    \xskakset{moveid=1w}\xskakget{movefrom}--\xskakget{moveto}, \xskakset{moveid=1b}\xskakget{movefrom}--\xskakget{moveto}

    % set start position of rook:
    \renewcommand\xskak@rookshort@pos{h}
    \def\CastleRookFromFile#1{#1{b}{h}}

    \newchessgame[setpieces={Kc1,Rh1,kc8,rh8}]
    \chessboard
    \mainline{1. O-O O-O}
    \chessboard

    \xskakset{moveid=1w}\xskakget{movefrom}--\xskakget{moveto}, \xskakset{moveid=1b}\xskakget{movefrom}--\xskakget{moveto}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, seems to work! Now I can hide the "helper defs" in a new command, which will make handling easier.

Comment: I can add some keys for it, I only need to decide about a sensible names.